# Submodule forked repository fetching parent repository's branches

Tags: git

**TLDR:** Can I possibly check out the branches of a forked repository that is a git submodule? Right now it only appears to be checking out the parent repo's branches, even though it is detached HEAD with all my forked repo's recent commits.

---

There was an open-source library that I do not manage called `TheLibrary` that I added as a git submodule. Then I needed to modify the library and use it as a git submodule, so I forked it on github, added a new branch `modifications` and put my modifications on there.  Then I updated my project's `.gitmodules` file to contain my forked library's URL, like so:

```
[submodule "libs/TheLibrary"]
    path = libs/TheLibrary
    url = https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git
    branch = modifications
```

Then I did `git submodule sync` in terminal, which gave this result:

```
Synchronizing submodule url for 'libs/TheLibrary'
```

Then I went in to the `libs/TheLibrary` directory on the terminal, and when I did `git fetch` it gave me the branches from the parent repo (master, feature/FeatureA). However, my forked repository should only have these branches: (master, modifications).

When I did `git remote -v`, it gave this result:

```
origin  https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git (push)
```

When I do `git branch`, it has this:

```
* (HEAD detached at a1b2c3def)
feature/featureA
master
```

However, feature/featureA is just a pull request I did on the parent repository. My forked repository should have the `modifications` branch that I added.

When I do `git log`, it is showing all the recent commits from the `modifications` branch though.

**How do I check out the `modifications` branch so I can continue adding changes to the forked library, and push them to the remote repo? The purpose is that I want it to still be able to merge in updates from the parent repo into our own changes. Is that even possible? Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR: I couldn't update the existing module for it to work. I had to run this command with the `-b` flag and it worked:
`git submodule add -b modifications https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git`**

So, modifying an existing submodule manually didn't seem to work, even when I deleted the entire library folder (`libs/TheLibrary`) and recalled `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` (which re-clones it).

But when I did this:

`git submodule add -b modifications https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git`

It put it in the current folder by mistake (I guess I should have put the correct path as the last parameter), but when I went in there to see if it checked out the right branch (I did `git status`) it said:

```
On branch modifications
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/modifications'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

That means it worked! For good measure, I did `git branch` to see if it had the right branches:

```
  master
* modifications
```

and it did! So I think that it will always need to be done this way, with the command with the `-b` flag, not the way I was trying to manually update the submodule.

---

**Note**: Even after it worked, it added this in `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "TheLibrary"]
        path = TheLibrary
        url = https://github.com/TheLibrary/TheLibrary.git
        branch = modifications
```

Even though it is exactly the same as what I had entered before (other than the different path), it didn't work before. There might be some other behind-the-scenes things going on when you run the command, and I guess that manually modifying those few files isn't sufficient.

---

**Note 2:** When I finally got the right folder, I got this git error:

```
A git directory for 'libs/TheLibrary' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

So I ran this command with the `--force` option and verified that it worked:

`git submodule add --force -b modifications https://github.com/myUsername/TheLibrary.git`